# Laravel: route for static file name issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, static-files

I want to make kind of api for static files with versioning in such way:

`public/js`

```
public/js
  ├ script-1.1.js
  ├ script-1.2.js
  ├ ...
  └ script-2.1.js
```

`routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/js/{version}/script.js', function ($version) {
    return File::get(public_path() . '/js/script-'.$version.'.js');
})->where('version', '^\d+(\.\d+)*$');
```

---

The problem is that Laravel ignores this route anyway and trying to find static file.

I.e. this will return 404 page:

```
Route::get('/js/test/script.js', function() {
    return response('Echo', 200)
           ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
});
```

But this will return 'Echo':

```
Route::get('/js/test', function() {
    return response('Echo', 200)
           ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
});
```

How to perform routing on URL which has filename in the end? I can't find similar issues still or any examples.

Comment: `public` have `index.php` that is hole laravel app if u put other assets or core php file inside public folder laravel will not render it will serve by your server as this is basic standard of server

Comment: and all your request 1st goes to `server` then `laravel` app so your above assets will render by server not laravel

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I use `Route::get('/js/{version}/{file}')` and process `$file` variable in the callback function then?

Comment: no need to create `api` if u put file in `public` folder it url will be created by server  like `domain.com/publicFolderAllComesHere`

Comment: What if there are no static files in public folder and I want to create it dynamically?

Comment: yes that creating u can do dynamic

Comment: So, seems `'/js/{version}/{file}'` is the correct path with parameters for this purpose. I need to parse `$file` variable for extension only.

Comment: yes u can use that